# Encrypt password in angular using crypto service

Tags: angularjs, cryptojs

Being a newbie to angular I'm stuck in doing encryption using crypto service on angular side, while i need to decrypt the password on my server where I'm using JAVA.

however I managed to get part of my answer , but still was unable to decrypt the salt in java.

[Converting Java's PBEWithMD5AndDES to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990630/converting-javas-pbewithmd5anddes-to-javascript/39004235#39004235)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use HTTPS? CryptoJS doesn't provide any cryptographic primitive that would give you *any* real security of sending a password across the internet. You'd need asymmetric crypto.

Comment: I'm already using HTTPS, but would like an additional security layer.

Comment: what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @phil: I am trying to encrypt the password on javascript and decrypt it on JAVA using PBEWithMD5AndDDES

Comment: @ArtjomB. saw your JAVA encryption in ideone , but couldn't find a proper method to decrypt the cipher.

Comment: @TechHunger - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js just use these crypto-js libraries. Wrap up a angular service, to call the libs, inject it into your controller or component, and modify the password before you send it.

Comment: Also (I don't know Java) but PBEWithMD5AndDDES sounds like it's a 1 way hash, so you should be doing this entirely server-side, not client-side.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Be aware of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266187). Also, the code my answer you've linked to is not very secure and I don't know if it is at all applicable to your situation, so I won't provide you with decryption code.